# Response Data not passed through json

Tags: java, php, jquery, json

The following script is suppossed to return for me  the requests booked  and append the data I got through json to html.

```
function readUsers() {
    //display ajax loader animation
    $( '#ajaxLoadAni' ).fadeIn( 'slow' );

    $.ajax({
        url: 'user_transactions/get_request',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( response ) {
            alert(response)
            for( var i in response ) {
                response[ i ].updateLink = updateUrl + '/' + response[ i ].id;
                response[ i ].deleteLink = delUrl + '/' + response[ i ].id;
            }

            //clear old rows
            $( '#records' ).html( '' );

            //append new rows
            $( '#readTemplate' ).render( response ).appendTo( "#records" );

            //hide ajax loader animation here...
            $( '#ajaxLoadAni' ).fadeOut( 'slow' );
        }
    });
} // end readrequest
```

I am able to get the data from the  url but when I alert the response , it is empty , how can I pass the data through the success function?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have a good response from the server side. First, define the type of you request, so add the type in your ajax request setting type: 'POST' or 'GET'. It would be better if you post here the server side code.